# Rails 7 bootstrap alert is not been dismissed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-5

I have followed this article https://www.bootrails.com/blog/rails-7-bootstrap-5-tutorial/ to display a bootstrap alert on my rails 7.0 app.

The alert is been displayed but not been dismissed when I click on the close button.
Here is my code inside application.html.erb

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <%= value %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap 5.1 has `data-bs-dismiss` attribute, not `data-dismiss`. Make sure you have "alert" plugin. According to their documentation, compiled javascript of Bootstrap has it.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/alerts/#dismissing
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/download/#compiled-css-and-js

Answer (score 1):

This is the Bootstrap 5 version

```
<button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you created your rails app with:

`rails new APP_NAME --css=bootstrap ...`

Which creates your app with `ESBUILD` and leaves you with a `app/javascripts/application.js` file looking like this:

```
// Entry point for the build script in your package.json
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "./controllers"
import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap"
```

You now need to code in the alert to use the imported bootstrap.

Add this below the `bootstrap` import line:

```
// Alerts
var alertList = document.querySelectorAll('.alert')
var alerts =  [].slice.call(alertList).map(function (element) {
  return new bootstrap.Alert(element)
});
```

This will turn on the event handlers

More can be found on the Bootstrap Docs page for each of the Components (the same applies to Modals and Popovers)

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/alerts/#initialize